Border-Radius for Table Cells in TCPDF
I'm currently using TCPDF for generating PDFs, and I'm trying to apply border-radius to tables in my document. However, I’ve noticed that border-radius CSS styles are not being applied as expected. My goal is to have tables or table cells with rounded corners to enhance the design of the document.
Could you please let me know if there is a way to enable border-radius functionality within TCPDF, or if there’s a recommended workaround to achieve a similar effect? Additionally, if there are any planned updates for enhanced CSS support in TCPDF, I’d be interested to know.
Thank you for your assistance.

Could you please share the code that doesn't give the expected result?

